# Making only the outer vector in vector<vector<int>> fixed

Tags: c++

I want to create a `vector<vector<int>>` where the outer vector is fixed (always containing the same vectors), but the inner vectors can be changed. For example:

```
int n = 2; //decided at runtime
assert(n>0);
vector<vector<int>> outer(n); //outer vector contains n empty vectors

outer.push_back(vector<int>()); //modifying outer vector - this should be error

auto outer_it = outer.begin();
(*outer_it).push_back(3); //modifying inner vector. should work (which it does).
```

I tried doing simply `const vector<vector<int>>`, but that makes even the inner vectors `const`.

Is my only option to create my own custom `FixedVectors` class, or are there better ways out there to do this?

Comment: Do you need n to be decideable at runtime?  Or can it be a compile time constant?

Comment: Have you considered using a const array?

Comment: why not use an array to create a constant array size? i dont see a reason why you would need to make it specifically a vector.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley Thanks for pointing this out. Yeah, it has to be decidable at runtime.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a vector of vectors. What problem does it cause that the outer vector is mutable? Just don't change it.

Comment: @ATaylor: a const array would have const elements, which means you couldn't modify their contents.

Comment: @KerrekSB: is there any use of `const` to which your argument cannot be applied? And if not, are you in effect saying that `const` is pointless in the first place? And if so, are you saying that deliberately? ;-) Once we know a way of achieving the degree of constness we want, then we can decide whether or not it's worth the effort to achieve.

Comment: @SteveJessop: But the OP's case is *not* const. It's sort of "a little bit const, once we're done modifying it".

Comment: @KerrekSB: True, but that wasn't my question to you. `const` is often used to mean "not modified in a particular context even though it is modified beforehand", that's why we pass const-reference parameters. We could pass non-const references and just not modify the object. What's different here is that the questioner wants a vector that's "structurally" const with modifiable members, and that just so happens not to be the semantics of `const` for vector.

Comment: Note that the standard quite easily *could* provide a sequence container with contiguous storage that isn't resizable. It lies part way between `std::array` and `std::vector`, or you could think of it as a wrapper for `new[]` (or for an Allocator object) that provides RAII and the container interface. It's just that the standard can't do *all* the thinking for everyone. I don't see any disadvantage in writing that container, other than the effort to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the outer vector into a class which just provides at, begin, end and operator []. Let the class take only have one constructor taking its capacity.

This most probably the best way.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see you suggested wrapping yourself

Answer (score 2):

by [definition](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/),

> Vectors are sequence containers representing arrays that can change in
>   size. Just like arrays, vectors use contiguous storage locations for
>   their elements, which means that their elements can also be accessed
>   using offsets on regular pointers to its elements, and just as
>   efficiently as in arrays. But unlike arrays, their size can change
>   dynamically, with their storage being handled automatically by the
>   container.

if you aren't looking to have a data structure that changes in size, a vector probably isn't the best choice for an outer layer, How about using an array of vectors. This way the array is of a fixed size and cannot be modified, while still having the freedom of having its size declared in runtime.

```
vector<int> *outer;
int VectSize;
cout >> "size of vector array?"
cin >> VectSize;
outer = new vector<int>[VectSize]; //array created with fixed size
outer.push_back() //not happening
```

Answer (score 1):

```
const vector<unique_ptr<vector<int>>> outer = something(n);
```

For the something, you might write a function, like this:

```
vector<unique_ptr<vector<int>>> something(int n)
{
    vector<unique_ptr<vector<int>>> v(n);
    for (auto & p : v)
        p.reset(new vector<int>);
    return v;
}
```